# In meteor: How do I create a form based on an object ID if I can't get the ID through the URL?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I have a collection where my URL is routed to

/groups/(groupid)

and in this group I have one or more specific events (based on a subsctiption/helper with computation)

Open Event(s):
event

Now say I want to create a Card for each of them containing a form to update the event:

**UpdateEventForm.html**

```
<template name="UpdateEventForm">
    {{#quickForm collection="Events" doc=event id="updateEventForm" type="update">
</template>
```

**UpdateEventForm.js**

```
Template.UpdateEventForm.onCreated(function(){
    var self = this;
    var id = ???
    self.subscribe('singleEvent', id);
});

Template.UpdateEventForm.helpers({

});
```

What I don't understand is how do I simply pass the ID of the event to the JS of the helper so I can subscribe to it and create my helpers etc.

Comment: In a different implementation where I could use the URL I did this:
var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');

Comment: what do you want to store in `id` ?

Comment: the _id of the event object that I am updating